# Unable to upload images on nginx server greater than 6 mb

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.2

I am trying to upload images to nginx server. I have changed in php.ini such as
upload_max_filesize = 12M and in nginx.conf such as client_max_body_size = 30M.
i am trying to upload 3 images at a time. If size of 3 image are less than 6mb , images are successfully uploaded but when images are greater than 6mb , it returns only '' and images are not uploaded.
How to solve this issue??

Comment: have you checked post_max_size value in php ?

Comment: I changed post_max_size = 20M but not working

Comment: Do you have timeout? Maybe the proxy timeout settings in nginx needs to be modified ?

Comment: Can you tell me what changes i have to do??

Comment: try change `proxy_send_timeout = 300` and `proxy_read_timeout = 300`  in your nginx settings this means 300 seconds the default is `60`. this if you have apache behind nginx

Comment: if you are using php-fpm (fastcgi) then use these instead `fastcgi_send_timeout` and `fastcgi_read_timeout`

Comment: In which file i have to do changes.. nginx.conf

Comment: In http or server

Comment: add the changes to nginx.conf inside http section

Comment: not working thid

Comment: Then you need to provide the error message that you see in nginx error log and in the browser and add them to your question

Comment: It doen't return error only gives ' '

Answer (score 1):

you have to look for below settings

```
 upload_max_filesize = 20M
 post_max_size = 21M
```

Comment: $this->base64Image = $base64Image;
$this->image_name  = $image_name;
$this->extension = 'png';
$this->ValidateAndUpload();
for($i=0;$i < count($this->uploadDir);$i++)
{
  $image = array(
    "name" => $image_name,
    "path1" => base_path().'/public/products/original/',
    "path" => base_path().'/public/products/'.$this->uploadDir[$i]['folder'].'/',
    "width" => $this->uploadDir[$i]['width'],
    "height" => $this->uploadDir[$i]['height'],
    "compress_ratio" => $this->uploadDir[$i]['compress']
  );
   CompressImage::dispatch($image)->delay(now()->addMinutes(2));

Comment: try uploading single image greater than 6mb. seems base64 encoding has some limit